# How to find the largest N elements in a list in R?

Tags: r, list, sorting, indexing, max

I have a list of floats in R. For a given integer, N, I want to find the **indices** of the largest N values in my list. So for example, if N is 2, I want to find the indices of the two largest values in my list. How do I do this?

I cannot reorder my list. This is why I need the indices.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
order(R, decreasing=TRUE)[1:N]
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is an alternative:

```
N <- 2
v <- c(3,  9, 11,  18,  5)
tail(order(v), N)
# [1] 3 4
```

Answer (score 6):

All of the other current answers require a call to `order` that will run in O(M log M) time. If N is much smaller than the total number of elements M, a quicker way is to partially sort the list and then to extract the indices greater than or equal to the N'th largest. This has O(M + N log N) running time and will be much quicker for large M.

```
v <- list(1,7,4,3,9,1,2,3,0,1,2)
vec <- unlist(v)
N <- 3
partial <- length(v) - N + 1
Nth <- sort(vec, partial = partial)[partial]
indexes <- which(vec >= Nth)
vec[indexes]
```

Note this will not deal with ties in the list. There is a longer discussion [here](http://johnreid.github.io/2018/09/partial-sort).

It is idiomatic to store numeric data in a vector not a list. Hence the call to `unlist` above.

As a function, this can be implemented like so:

```
maxn <- function(x, n) {
  partial <- length(x) - n + 1
  x[x >= sort(x, partial = partial)[partial]]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I've found this code very useful. I have adapted it slightly to account for ties (by just looking at the unique values of x), and to allow the user to select max/min [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74453566/10366237). I haven't implemented the code as efficiently as possible though, and I am sure it's asymptotic runtime is quite a bit higher than this initial code.

Answer (score 4):

You probably mean vector and not a list, and here's an example:

```
v = c(1,7,4,3,9)
v[order(-v)][1:3]
#[1] 9 7 4
```

Re comment:

```
order(-v)[1:3]
#[1] 5 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works as well:

```
x <- list(1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5)
which(x %in% max(unlist(x)))
```